# Optimized way to retrieve user data ( Chat mysql)

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, optimization

I have a nodeJS app where i should receive users conversation since it's a messaging app .
I have 2 mysql tables .
Messages :
[Messages DB structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16rIe.png)

And Conversations [Conversations DB structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFYIG.png)

My goal is to have a page where user can see the conversations he had or is having , with the username of the user , his profile pic , the last sent message , if it's read or no , and the last date .

Any idea on how to do this ?
I can do it but in 2 seperate api calls , what better ways do you propose ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. "Recommend me a.." type questions are off topic here, I'm afraid; we don't do opinions, we do facts :)

Comment: 1 vs 2 API calls is not a big deal.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.  Don't use pictures of text; paste the text in.